# Exclude dates within a range in SQL/Big Query

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, between

I am trying to exclude any data that has more than 10 days between Min_Sort_Date and Max_Sort_Date.

This is the initial query I have to start with:

select
srt_bin_id,
Min(srt_cred_tmst) as Min_Sort_Date,
Max(srt_cred_tmst)as Max_Sort_Date,
Count(trkg_id) as count_of_packages,
Max(srt_loc_id) as Store
from `bda-prd.dp_logistics.bqt_lgs_rets_rpt`
where srt_cred_tmst > "2022-08-13"
Group by 1

Any tips on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory is good, you can use DATE_DIFF function with BigQuery to do something like:

> select
> DATE_DIFF(Max(srt_cred_tmst), Min(srt_cred_tmst), DAY) AS DAYS_GAP from
> Database.Table

Like that you will be able to calculate the gap, and exclude rows with a where condition when DAYS_GAP >= 10

Comment: when I try this an error message pops up "unrecognized name DAYS_GAP": select 
srt_bin_id,
min(srt_cred_tmst) Min_Sort_Date,
max(srt_cred_tmst) Max_Sort_Date,
date_diff(max(srt_cred_tmst), min(srt_cred_tmst), day)as days_gap,
count(trkg_id) count_of_packages,
Max(srt_loc_id) Store
from `kohls-bda-prd.dp_logistics.bqt_lgs_amzn_rets_rpt`
where srt_cred_tmst > "2022-08-13"
and days_gap <= 10
Group by 1

Comment: You have to do the where condition in another function. You can do something like:
`With data AS (
 select
  srt_bin_id,
  min(srt_cred_tmst) Min_Sort_Date,
  max(srt_cred_tmst) Max_Sort_Date,
  date_diff(max(srt_cred_tmst), min(srt_cred_tmst), day) Days_Gap,
  count(trkg_id) count_of_packages,
  Max(srt_loc_id) Store
 from kohls-bda-prd.dp_logistics.bqt_lgs_amzn_rets_rpt
 where srt_cred_tmst > "2022-08-13"
 Group by 1
)
SELECT
 *
FROM data
WHERE Days_Gap >= 10`